System size scaling of sums of random lognormal variables
I will not go too much into details, but my question may be summarized as follows:
Suppose you have a system of size $N$ and two lognormal-distributed random variables $A$ and $B$ associated with said system. The mean value of the log of these random variables scales linearly with system size, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\langle \log A \rangle = a\cdot N, \ \ \ \langle \log B \rangle = b\cdot N.
\end{equation}
Now I am interested into a new random variable $C = A + \beta B$ where $\beta$ is a perturbation parameter. Specifically, I want to understand why
\begin{equation}
\langle \log C \rangle = c \cdot N
\end{equation}
with $a < c < b$ and c approaching $b$ with larger $\beta$. These relations are based on numerical findings, but I would like to understand this analytically. Any input is appreciated! Thanks.

Sums of lognormals are not lognormal and are lack closed form expressions. If the variances also scale up with N, then the problem is easy: the scaling just means that the units you use to measure things in scale up, and the final formula follows obviously. However, if the variance does not scale nicely with system size, then I suspect it is just an approximation.

The variances of A, B, and C indeed also scale like N. However, I do not really get your point. Could you possibly elaborate?

This is probably better asked in the statistics community: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

How does the variance of the logarithm $\Delta(\ln X)^2$ scale? I’m also guessing that you are mostly interested in the thermodynamic limit $N\to\infty$
